# TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' - Error recieved in IRC weather bot in Python

Tags: python, irc, weather

Okay, so I've got a bit of Python IRC Bot code, and I recently added a weather command to it, but it doesn't seem to work... heres the code

```
# Import some necessary libraries.
import socket  
import time 
import httplib

def commands(nick,channel,message):
    if message.find('!test')!=-1:
    ircsock.send('PRIVMSG %s :%s: test complete\r\n' % (channel,nick))
    elif message.find('!help')!=-1:
        ircsock.send('PRIVMSG %s :%s: My other command is test.\r\n' % (channel,nick))
    elif message.find('!sex')!=-1:
        ircsock.send('PRIVMSG %s :%s: But why?\r\n' % (channel,nick))
    elif message.find('!quit')!=-1:
        ircsock.send('QUIT :For the bones of the weak shall support me\r\n')
        die('Quit command given')
    elif message.find('!op')!=-1:
        ircsock.send('MODE %s +o :%s\n' % (channel,nick))
    elif message.find('!deop')!=-1:
        ircsock.send('MODE %s -o :%s\n' % (channel,nick))
    elif message.find('!weather')!=-1:
        tmp = message.find(':!weather')
        city = tmp[1].strip()
        reqest_str = '/laika_zinas/?city=' + city
        c = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.1188.lv")
        c.request("GET", reqest_str)
        ra = c.getresponse()
        datas = ra.read()
        temp, wind = tpars(datas)
        ircsock.send('PRIVMSG %s :%s: [+] Temp: '+ temp +' C | Wind: '+ wind +' m/s' % (channel,nick))
        c.close()
# Some basic variables used to configure the bot        
server = "n0cht.bawx.net" # Server
channel = "#python" # Channel
botnick = "PyleDrivr" # Your bots nick

def ping(ircmsg): # This is our first function! It will respond to server Pings.
    ircsock.send("PONG "+ ircmsg +"\n") 
    print("Ping replied\n\r")

def sendmsg(chan , msg): # This is the send message function, it simply sends messages to the channel.
    ircsock.send("PRIVMSG "+ chan +" :"+ msg +"\n")

def joinchan(chan): # This function is used to join channels.
    ircsock.send("JOIN "+ chan +"\n")


ircsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ircsock.connect((server, 6667)) # Here we connect to the server using the port 6667
ircsock.send("USER "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" "+ botnick +" :PyleDrivr\n") # user authentication
ircsock.send("NICK "+ botnick +"\n") # here we actually assign the nick to the bot

joinchan(channel) # Join the channel using the functions we previously defined

while 1: # Be careful with these! it might send you to an infinite loop
    ircmsg = ircsock.recv(2048) # receive data from the server
    ircmsg = ircmsg.strip('\n\r') # removing any unnecessary linebreaks.
    print(ircmsg) # Here we print what's coming from the server
    if ircmsg.find(' PRIVMSG ')!=-1:
        nick=ircmsg.split('!')[0][1:]
        channel=ircmsg.split(' PRIVMSG ')[-1].split(' :')[0]
        commands(nick,channel,ircmsg)
    if ircmsg.find("PING :") != -1: # if the server pings us then we've got to respond!
        ping(ircmsg)
```

Now, when I run the bot, it works just fine, but then this happens when I issue the command:

```
<wh0r3[mint]> !weather 99654
* PyleDrivr has quit (Client exited)
```

And here's what the term shows:

```
:wh0r3[mint]!~wh0r3@n0cht-D1D272D.gci.net PRIVMSG #lobby :!weather 99654
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyledrivr.py", line 65, in <module>
    commands(nick,channel,ircmsg)
  File "pyledrivr.py", line 22, in commands
    city = tmp[1].strip()
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I have no idea what this means or how to fix it. and ideas?

Comment: "I have no idea what this means or how to fix it." Please start by learning the basics of python. [Here's a relevant excerpt from the documentation about exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
tmp = message.find(':!weather')
```

assigns an integer to `tmp`: the position at which the string `':!weather'` was found in `message` (see [`find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find)). It may not even be found at all, since you check in the line above that `'!weather'` is in `message`, not `':!weather'`.

Then you try and access `tmp[1]`. But `tmp` is just a number; it doesn't have a `[1]`.

If you want to get the substring of message that follows `'!weather'`, you could do this:

```
city = message[message.find('!weather')+8:].strip()
```

(8 being the length of `'!weather'`)

Or you might find it easier to use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
city = message.split('!weather')[1].strip()
```